# Unkown type error when using typedef struct

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I know there are a lot of questions asking this, but I have looked at many of them and I still can't figure out what the problem is. It must be some simple mistake, but I have compared this struct declaration and use with another that I use in this same project (with no errors) and they look the same to me.

I have this struct declared in trie.h:

```
#ifndef TRIE_H
#define TRIE_H

#include "fw.h"
#include "linked.h"

#define ALPHABET_SIZE 26

typedef struct T_node
{
   /* number of times this word has been found 
      (stored at end of word) */
   int freq;
   /* is_end is true if this T_node is the end of a word 
      in which case it */
   int is_end;
   /* each node points to an array of T_nodes
      depending on what letter comes next */
   struct T_node *next[ALPHABET_SIZE];
} T_node;

int add_word(T_node *root, char *word);
T_node *create_node(void);
void max_freqs(T_node *root, int num, List *freq_words, char *word,
               int word_len, int i);
void free_trie(T_node *root);

#endif
```

I use it in fw.h:

```
#ifndef FW_H
#define FW_H

#include <stdio.h>

#include "trie.h"

#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1

int read_file(FILE *in, T_node *root);
char *read_long_word(FILE *in);

#endif
```

And I get this error:

```
In file included from trie.h:4:0,
             from trie.c:5:
fw.h:11:25: error: unknown type name T_node
 int read_file(FILE *in, T_node *root);
                         ^
```

Edit: I don't think this is a duplicate of the linked question. If you look at the top answer, it seems that the struct provided is in the same format that my T_node currently is in. Also, I am not getting the same error as in that question.

Comment: Can you please post َa [mcve]?

Comment: @gzh It's not a duplicate of that, note that in this case there is `struct T_node *next[ALPHABET_SIZE];`, which is correct.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi Ok, I put the full header files. I don't think they are relevant, but they may be useful.

Comment: @dumbitdownjr Your question was answered below. Take a look. You need to ensure that a file is only included once. A simple method to achieve that is to use so called *include guards*, just `#ifndef MY_FANCY_HEADER_FILE` and then in the next line `#define MY_FANCY_HEADER_FILE` and at the end of the file `#endif`. That way, even if you include the file multiple times, the compiler will only include it's content until you define `MY_FANCY_HEADER_FILE` macro, and thus it will only be included once.

Comment: The `fw.h` in the question doesn't use `T_node` at all and doesn't have the line in the error message. It looks like you accidentally included `linked.h`? Either way, if you include `fw.h` in `trie.h`, it doesn't make sense to use something defined *after* that inclusion in `fw.h` because it won't see it.

Comment: @DanielH Oops, good catch. When I was editing I pasted the wrong header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message

```
In file included from trie.h:4:0,
             from trie.c:5:
fw.h:11:25: error: unknown type name T_node
 int read_file(FILE *in, T_node *root);
                         ^
```

says that `trie.c` includes `trie.h` which includes `fw.h`.

But we have also seen that `fw.h` includes `trie.h`. And so we have a full circle.

---

If possible, use a forward declared struct `int read_file(FILE *in, struct T_node *root);` and remove the `trie.h` include from `fw.h`.

Comment: So this isn't allowed? I need fw.h in trie.c, and I also need trie.h in fw.h. Does this mean that I should combine them into one header file?

Comment: You *will* have to organize the code so that you don't get a circular include. You don't need a full declaration of the struct to just pass a pointer to it as a parameter. For that it is enough with a forward declaration `struct T_node;`.